# Awesomium screen capture multi thread?

Tags: c#, awesomium

I want to take a screenshot of multiple web pages at once using ASP.net and c#, or using thread, using Awesomium. However with the `WebCore` I don’t think that is possible.

I even tried creating a console application for this issue with no avail due to WebCore.

My only other idea which I haven't done yet, is to call a standalone console application via `Process.Start()`.

Does anyone know if and how I can go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got around this by creating a separate console app with the Awesomium functionality in it, and by passing arguments to that separate app via arguments.